# Convert Character Encoding, and Check Encoding for Issues

Tags: mysql, mysql-5.6, alter-table, character-set, encoding

I'm planning to convert a table from `utf8` (`_general_ci`) to `utf8mb4` (`utf8mb4_unicode_ci`). I want to make sure I don't have any malformed data after the conversion though so I was planning to duplicate the data, run a join on the two tables, and see if there are any differences.

Is this a good way to go about it?

1.

```
Create table Email_utf8mb4  like Email;
```

2.

```
insert into Email_utf8mb4 select * from Email;
```

3.

```
ALTER TABLE Email_utf8mb4 
CONVERT TO CHARACTER SET utf8mb4 
COLLATE utf8mb4_unicode_ci;
```

4.

```
select * from Email as old
join Email_utf8mb4 as new  
on old.notificationid =new.notificationid 
and (old.subject <> new.subject OR old.content <>
    new.content)
```

4.5. Assuming no rows are returned...

5.

```
drop Email;
```

6.

```
RENAME TABLE Email_utf8mb4 to Email;
```

`subject` and `content` are the only alpha columns in my table.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That won't fix or recognize any malformed data *already* in the table.

Yes, that is a good technique.  `ALTER..CONVERT TO..` does the bulk of the work.  And, since utf8 is a subset of utf8mb4, there should be no differences discovered in step 4.

However, there is still a possibility of step 4 showing something.  This is because the definition of "equal" (hence `<>`) is different for `_general_ci` versus `_unicode_ci`.

For example, in German, `ss` and `ß` are unequal in _general_ci (either utf8 or utf8mb4), but equal in virtually all other collations.  If, for example, you currently have a `UNIQUE` (or `PRIMARY KEY`) with a value that differs in just `ss` vs `ß`, the conversion will have a problem with "duplicate key" error.

Another problematic pair:  `ae` vs `æ`

A different issue - not equality, but ordering - `Ð` < `E` for _unicode_ci, but not for some other collations.

Meanwhile, as long as you are changing the `COLLATION`, you may as well go  to the newer Unicode Algorithm in `utf8mb4_unicode_520_ci`.

Comment: Malformed data already present is fine. So it sounds like step 4 might bring false positives but wouldn't miss any issues, is that right?

Comment: @user3783243 - Give it a test run; that is, abort in 4.5 if rows were returned.  Then let's discuss them.

Comment: No rows were returned so I think I'm good to go.